# Can I get EntityFramework 4.1 to return queries that return results that consider data in both the DbSet.Local and database?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

Say I have a table in a database called TestDB with a table called Table1 which contains two columns

```
ID
Name
```

In this table ,there is two row,

```
ID 1 and Name 'Row1'
ID 2 and Name 'Row2'
```

If this is my code

```
var currObj = Table1.Where(o => o.Name.Contains("Row1")).FirstOrDefault();
currObj.Name = "Row1a";

var a = Table1.Where(o => o.Name.Contains("Row1a")).FirstOrDefault();
var b = Table1.Local.Where(o => o.Name.Contains("Row1a")).FirstOrDefault();
```

a is going to return null, whereas b is going to return a value.

if I do this though

```
var c = Table1.Where(o => o.Name.Contains("Row2")).FirstOrDefault();
var d = Table1.Local.Where(o => o.Name.Contains("Row2")).FirstOrDefault();
```

then c will return something, but d will not.

For me, this seems unintuitive because there is two different places the data could be. For every query I do, I have to look in the database, and the Local object and merge them together. Like if it's changed in the local object, I have to take that into account. Does Entity Framework have any mechanism for this, which would consider BOTH the data in the database AND the local at the same time?

So if I went

```
var e =  Table1.AMagicSolution.Where(o => o.Name.Contains("Row1a")).FirstOrDefault();
var f = Table1.AMagicSolution.Where(o => o.Name.Contains("Row2")).FirstOrDefault();
```

then e and f would both return something (f from the database and e from the Local object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expectation is little bit strange. EF context works like a unit of work = it is used to process single logical transaction and because of that you should try to design your application in the way that it knows if the record is in the local storage or not.

If for any reason your application doesn't know if the record is in the local storage you should always separate queries to the local storage and to the database! Reasons are performance and unnecessary roundtrips to the database. Use helper like in following example to query the local storage first and only if record is not present in the local storage query the database:

```
public static Table1 AMagicSolution(this IQueryable<Table1> query, string name)
{
    var item = Table1.Local.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(name)).FirstOrDefault(); 
    if (item != null)
    {
        item = Table1.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(name)).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return item;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that is a little better than the other solution, although performance isn't an issue for me at this time. The only thing I would say about this solution though is that I wish it was more generic. I would need to write a specific method for every class for every query. It would be great if you could just pass a DbSet<T> as the table and also the linq query you want to run on it as a func. But I've played around with it, and sadly, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I guess that the above code should be: if (item == null) instead of if (item !=null)

Answer (score 1):

Not much different from your other question.

```
Table1.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Unchanged)
    .Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(Table1Type) 
           && o => o.Name.Contains("Row1a"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738497.aspx): "The EntityState is a bit field, so state entries for multiple states can be retrieved in one call by doing a bitwise OR of more than one EntityState values."

Comment: mmm can't test this at the moment, will test when I get back in. If I also add EntityState.Modified to this, what row will I get for the changed rows? will it get the original data as it is in the database or the changed data?

Comment: you'd get the modified unsaved values.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Entities class is now a DbContext so I can't run that, I think I could probably use the ChangeTracker to achieve the same type of thing though.

Comment: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/accessing-objectcontext-features-from-ef-4-1-dbcontext/